# How to get the id of the user that send the request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

In my app there is a MultiFriendSelector to invite friends.

I want that the recipient see in the canvas page the id of the user that has sent the request via MultiFriendSelector.

I need to get the id without using PHP or other server side language, but I can use javascript  or fbml for example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Multifriend selector is a **[user-user request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/)** and a typical request looks the below (from attribute will tell you the request senders information)

```
{
  "id": "REQUEST_OBJECT_ID", 
  "application": {
    "name": "APP_DISPLAY_NAME", 
    "canvas_name": "APP_NAME",  // This is identical to the app namespace
    "namespace": "APP_NAMESPACE", 
    "id": "APP_ID"
  }, 
  "from": {
    "name": "SENDER_USER_NAME", 
    "id": "SEND_USER_ID"
  }, 
  "message": "Check out this Awesome Request!", 
  "created_time": "2012-01-24T00:43:22+0000", 
  "type": "apprequest"
}
```

Comment: but how can I get the "from" attribute in the canvas page ?

Comment: please check the link (scroll down), you will find how to read/delete outstanding requests. That should help